# How do I search for first_name and last_name combined in the UI

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my existing query I can only search for first_name seperately and last_name seperately.For example the customers info is coming from customers tale and names are from first_name and last_name column.First_name column has a name "John" and last_name column has "Doe".If I search in the UI for only John or Doe it is displaying the whole data of the customer.If I search for 'John Doe' it is not displaying the customer details.

`customers = customers.where("identifier LIKE ? OR first_name LIKE ? OR last_name LIKE ? " + "OR customers.email LIKE ? OR institutional_groups.name LIKE ?", q, q, q, q, q) if q.present?`

How can I modify this?

Answer (score 1):

You could concatenate your `first_name` and `last_name` columns like this and use that value to search:

```
customers = customers.where("identifier 
LIKE ? OR (first_name || ' ' || last_name) 
LIKE ? OR customers.email LIKE ? OR institutional_groups.name 
LIKE ?", q, "%#{q}%", q, q) 
if q.present?
```

Comment: I can't retrive the data.In console I'am getting like this.
 SELECT `customers`.* FROM `customers` INNER JOIN `institutional_groups` ON `institutional_groups`.`id` = `customers`.`institutional_group_id` WHERE (identifier LIKE '%Vishnu K%' OR (first_name || ' ' || last_name)
                                  LIKE '%%Vishnu K%%' OR customers.email LIKE '%Vishnu K%' OR institutional_groups.name
                                  LIKE '%Vishnu K%') AND `customers`.`institutional_group_id` = 195326047

Comment: In last_name it should give "k" but it is giving in the first_name

Comment: Try this: customers = customers.where("identifier LIKE ? OR (first_name || ' ' || last_name) LIKE ? OR (last_name || ' ' || first_name) LIKE ? OR customers.email LIKE ? OR institutional_groups.name LIKE ?", "%#{q}%", "%#{q}%", "%#{q}%", "%#{q}%", "%#{q}%") if q.present?

Comment: No its not working and I cant search with first name now it works only for last name.I need to search with first name seperately and also search with last name seperately and also both combined.

Comment: So there's 3 cases you need: search for first name match, last name match, and first and last name match. What's your current query and which cases are still not working?

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the four cases:

- **Only first name** search `first_name LIKE :query`
- **Only last name** search `last_name LIKE :query`
- **First name followed by last name** search `CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE :query`
- **Last name followed by first name** search `CONCAT(last_name, ' ', first_name) LIKE :query`

For **partial match**, you can surround `query` with `%`.

```
Customer.where("
   first_name LIKE :query OR 
   last_name LIKE :query OR 
   CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE :query OR
   CONCAT(last_name, ' ', first_name) LIKE :query
", query: "%#{query}%")
```

For **exact match**, remove the `%` character.

```
Customer.where("
  first_name LIKE :query OR 
  last_name LIKE :query OR 
  CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE :query OR
  CONCAT(last_name, ' ', first_name) LIKE :query
", query: query)
```

References:

- CONCAT function (https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-string-functions/postgresql-concat-function/)